# rotation figure (canvas) by the triangle on the mouse movement event

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I am try to make the rotation figure (canvas) by the triangle on the
mouse movement event - the result is not as needed yet. Tell me where
an error.

```
calculateAngle(e) {
        if (!e) return;
        let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
            vx = e.clientX - this.startX,
            vy = e.clientY - this.startY;
        this.angle = Math.atan2(vy, vx);
    }

    binding() {
        const self = this;
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            self.calculateAngle(e);
        });
    }

    render() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.startX, this.startY);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle * (Math.PI / 180));
        ctx.translate(-this.startX, -this.startY);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY);
        ctx.lineTo(this.startX + this.width / 2, this.startY + this.height);
        ctx.lineTo(this.startX - this.width / 2, this.startY + this.height);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    class Triangle {
        constructor(data) {
            this.startX = data.x;
            this.startY = data.y;
            this.angle = data.angle;
            this.width = data.width;
            this.height = data.height;
            this.binding();
        }}

Comment: const simpleTriangle = new Triangle({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 35,
        height: 70,
        angle: 0
    });
    (function run() {
        simpleTriangle.render();
        requestAnimationFrame(run);
    })();

Answer (score 0):

## `Math.atan2` returns angle in radians.

The error is in the render function where you are converting the rotation to radians. You don't need to do this as the return from `Math.atan2` is already in radians.

Also the render function can be improved to

```
render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,this.startX, this.startY); // set location of origin
                                                        // this is where everything
                                                        // is rotated around

    /*===================================================
    your code was incorrect
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * (Math.PI / 180));
    =====================================================*/

    // should be 
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo( this.width / 2, this.height);
    ctx.lineTo(-this.width / 2, this.height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restore default transform
}
```